# How Set the property based on feature selection in Wix features tree

Tags: wix

I have a feature in my installer WIX feature tree:

```
<Feature Id="Myfeature" Level="1" AllowAdvertise="yes">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="EnableMyFeature"/>
          </Feature>
```

Then I want to modify a config file, based on wheter feature is selected or not (change a value to true if selected, and false if not selected).

```
<ComponentGroup Id="EnableMyFeature" Directory="InstallDir">
  <Component Id="EnableAlarmMonitor" Guid="{142D13A4A-43D6-45ED-A6C4-7895F3891578}" KeyPath="yes">
    <util:XmlFile Id="MyFeature.config"
                  Action="setValue"
                  ElementPath="/configuration/myFeatureConfig/enable/option[\[]@region='enab'[\]]"
                  Name="load"
                  File="[#MyFeature.config]"
                  Value="[MY_FEATURE_SELECTED]" />
  </Component>
```

I have a property:

```
 <Property Id="MY_FEATURE_SELECTED" Value="false" Secure="yes"/>
```

The I set it to true, if feature gets selected:

```
<SetProperty Id="MY_FEATURE_SELECTED" Value="true" Sequence="execute" After="InstallInitialize">
  <![CDATA[&MyFeature=3]]>
</SetProperty>
```

Unfortunately, this way it does not work. Why ?

Comment: Did you schedule the custom action anywhere, either in a sequence or in response to a published controlevent?

Comment: After="InstallInitialize" , Sequence="execute"

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I missed that. (I thought it had to be scheduled separately.) Does a verbose log show the action execute and the property change? I'm guessing it has to be after CostFinalize.